# MISSISSIPPI combinations with the S's separated

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many combinations are there to arrange the letters in MISSISSIPPI requiring that the 2 S's must be separated?

I found there are 34650 combinations to arrange without restriction.

How to approach this question?

Comment: 'won't be stick' - what does it mean?

Comment: Spelling it right is a good start. Or is there only one P in your homework?

Comment: fixed, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: are you familiar with inclusion-exclusion theorem?

Comment: @Alex yes I do.

Comment: there are 4 S's in MISSISSIPI though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that the string will take the form of

$$*S█S█S█S*$$

where $█$ MUST have at least one character and $*$ can be of any length (even 0). I would suggest the following steps:

1. Find the number of ways you can put the $S$s (they can be in positions $(1,3,5,7)$, $(2,5,8,11)$, $(1,4,6,9)$, etc.)
2. Find the number of different strings you can make with $MIIIPPI$ (that's $MISSISSIPPI$ without the $S$s)
3. Multiply the two.

I leave the math for you to do.

Answer (score 0):

Find all possible ways we can arrange MIIIPPI: 7!/(4!*2!). Then "insert" four S into the 8 space between each possible arrangement of MIIIPPI, e.g. [1]M[2]I[3]I[4]I[5]P[6]P[7]I[8]; This is really ${8}\choose{4}$. Multiplying the two!