# MISSISSIPPI problem

Tags: combinatorics

**How many arrangement of the letters in MISSISSIPPI have at least 2 adjacent S's?**

I was thinking that I can glue two of the S's together, so there will be 9 letters plus the special letter SS, and the number of arrangements will be $10!/(2!2!4!)$, this is not the correct answer, but what is wrong with my reasoning.

(the correct answer is $11!/(4!4!2!)-7!/(4!2!)\binom{8}{4}$, I understand the solution)

Comment: In this case you account for the fact of having either 2 or 4 adjacent letters S, but not 3

Comment: I think you are counting twice the strings with "$SSS$" (and not "$SSSS$") in them and three times the ones with "$SSSS$".

Comment: @G. Sassatelli thanks, understand now

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697668)

Comment: Double counting.  It's *always* double counting....  e.g. if you glue two Ss as $\ss$. then you count ${\ss}MIIIIPPSS$ and $SSMIIIIPP\ss$ separately.  As well as $MIS{\ss}ISIPPI$ and $MI{\ss}SISIPPI$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Total arrangements of MISSISSIPPI:
$$\frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}=34650$$

Total arrangements of MIIIPPI:
$$\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}=105$$

... and ways to insert SSSS into the $8$ gaps without any adjacent Ss into each variant:
$$ {8 \choose 4 }= 70$$

So number of arrangements of MISSISSIPPI that have two Ss together:
$$ 34650-105\cdot 70 = 34650-7350 = 27300 $$

Your reasoning neglects the other ways that $2$ Ss can appear together.