# Combinations with duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sequence of n non-distinct numbers and I want to find the number of combinations of half the size.

For example:

Given 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1 there are 3 combinations of size 2:
0.5, 0.5
1, 1
1, 0.5

If I have all numbers that are the same, e.g. 1, 1, 1, 1, then there is only 1 combination of size 2: 1, 1.

Is there a algorithm/formula I can use to get what I want?

Comment: So you have $n$ objects. You want the number of ways to make objects of length exactly $\frac n2$. Looks like Multinomial theory. http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Structures.html#mul

Comment: Half the size? Then it is more handsome to work with $2n$ instead of $n$. I interpret the vague *non-distinct* as *not necessarily distinct*.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to apply the multinomial theory in this question? Sorry, I'm a rookie.

Comment: You seem to have the case $K=2$ of [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043710/algorithm-to-partition-a-multiset-into-k-equal-sized-multisets).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no known formula for counting these solutions *in polynomial time*.  The topic has been [broached in previous Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653780/possible-ways-to-have-n-bounded-natural-numbers-with-a-fixed-sum), but it can appear in a variety of contexts, so a clear statement of the known theory bears repeating at least once more. [Multinomials, as suggested in a Comment on the Question, solve a different kind of problem, counting the arrangements/permutations with specified repetitions of items, eg. the [MISSISSIPPI problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855369/mississippi-problem).]

You ask about splitting a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $M$ into two equal-size sub-multisets.  Obvious a necessary and sufficient condition for this to be possible is that the size (counting multiplicities of elements) of $M$ is an even integer, let's say $2n$.  However *counting* the number of ways this can be done depends on the details of those multiplicities (repetitions of items).  So we begin by taking a step back and going over the parameters needed to define $M$ as a multiset.

The basic difference between a *set* and a *multiset* is the requirement that every element in a set is distinguishable; there are no repetitions.  So every multiset $M$ has an underlying set $S$ which consists of the same elements but taken without regard to possible repetitions.  Conversely we can prescribe any multiset $M$ by specifying the underlying set $S$ that contains all its elements and a function $d:S \to \mathbb N$ which tells us the number of times such elements are repeated in $M$.  In that narrow way the repetitions will always be positive counting numbers.

In some contexts (including the present one!) it can be convenient to allow $S$ to be strictly bigger than the underlying set of $M$ and to assign "zero repetitions" to any elements appearing in $S$ but not in $M$.  The utility of this generalization will appear shortly, but we can already hint that in splitting $M = M_1 \cup M_2$, it may happen that some elements of $M$ would not appear in *both* sub-multisets, yet using the same set $S$ to prescribe both $M_1,M_2$ will simplify our expressions.

For each $i\in S$ we have a repetition count $d(i)$ for the number of times element $i$ appears in $M$.  Assume that the total size of $M$ is positive even integer $2n$, so that our task is to count the number of sub-multisets $M_1 \subseteq M$ which have size $n$.  Equivalently we are counting the number of ways $M = M_1 \cup M_2$ where the sizes of sub-multisets $M_1,M_2$ are equal.

Let $d_1:S\to \mathbb N$ and $d_2:S\to \mathbb N$ be the respective functions that provide the repetition counts for $M_1,M_2$.  By construction we have $d_1(i)+d_2(i)=d(i)$ for each $i\in S$. If the set $S$ is $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, then these values can be visualized by what statisticians call a $2\times m$ [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table):

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c} \hline
d_1(1) & d_1(2) & \ldots & d_1(m) & n \\ \hline
d_2(1) & d_2(2) & \ldots & d_2(m) & n \\ \hline
d(1)   & d(2)   & \ldots & d(m)   & 2n \end{array}
$$

where the *marginal sums* are shown as bottom row and rightmost column.

Counting the exact number of ways to fill in even such a simple contingency table with the given row and column sums is known to be a hard problem.  More precisely, from [Sampling Contingency Tables (1995)](http://www.mzlabs.com/JMPubs/Sampling%20Contingency%20Tables-Dyer.pdf) by Dyer, Kannan, and Mount:

> We will show that exactly counting contingency tables is hard, even in a very restricted case...
>
> **Theorem 1** The problem of determining the exact number of contingency tables with prescribed row and column sums is $\#P$-complete, even in the $2\times n$ case.

Here the $\#P$-completeness of this family of computations implies that if  a polynomial time algorithm for them exists, then $P=NP$, which is famously an open problem.  So while difficult, the problem of *counting* the number of specified contingency tables is important, and statisticians are thus interested in *approximating* those counts or in methods for *uniformly sampling* them.

A fairly recent (2015) paper in this area is [Random Sampling of Contingency Tables via Probabilistic Divide-and-Conquer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00070) by DeSalvo and Zhao.  Their references provide a sense of the history of such research.